# How to send tweet to target user?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I have some code:

```
  internal TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> UpdateTweet(string Tweet)
        {
            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = null;

             OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();

             tokens.AccessToken = accessToken;
             tokens.AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret;
             tokens.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
             tokens.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;


             tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, Tweet);


            return tweetResponse;
        }
```

This code send tweet to authenticated user but I need send to assigned user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tweet text should begin with "@<username>" to direct a tweet to a specific person. Keep in mind that this is still a public tweet (provided that the authenticated user is not protected). To send a private message from the authenticated user to another user, you can use the TwitterDirectMessage class or prefix a tweet with "d <username>".

So, to send a public tweet that is directed to a user, do like: @twit_er_izer Just wanted to say hello.

To send a direct message, do like: d twit_er_izer Just wanted to say hello.
(Or use the direct message class.)